# How do I parse a string into a DateTime, with a specific format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, parsing

I have a source where dates comes in this string form:

```
   Sat Sep 22 13:15:03 2018
```

Is there an easy way I can parse that into a DateTime in C#? I've tried with DateTime.(Try)Parse, but it doesn't seem to recognize this specific format...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact ("Sat Sep 22 13:15:03 2018", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", null)
```

Answer (score 6):

You should prefer [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) and `TryParseExact`; these methods let you specify the expected format(s) in your program.

The `DateTime.Parse` and `TryParse` methods are dangerous because they accept the current date/time format configured on the machine where the code is running -- which the user can change from the default -- along with a couple of culture-neutral formats. In other words, the user can change settings in Control Panel and break `Parse`/`TryParse`.

Answer (score 5):

Try [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

This code takes your date string and applies a format to create a DateTime object.

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

string dateString = "Sat Sep 22 13:12:03 2018";
string format = "ddd MMM dd HH':'mm':'ss yyyy";

DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Comment: This is missing the numeric day of the month after the abbreviated month name. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = "Sat Sep 22 13:15:03 2018";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```